# Is there a single word when the clock hands meet?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not sure if such word exists, but English is not my native language. The word I'm looking for describes the time when the clock hands overlap. In my language there is such a word, it is "cager", so the sentence

> It is now *cager*.

means

> It is now [the time when clock hands are overlapped].

This word is considered slang in my language, and I'm wondering if English has a similar word.

Comment: English *is* my native language and I don't know such a word.  I'd love to know what language "cager" is however.

Comment: It is Macedonian, written as „цагер“. I just figured it may have confused you as word which comes from "cage". "Cager" is just written in latin letters.

Comment: Eclipse ? ...   :D

Comment: Not that I make a habit of speaking ill of the dead, but this reminds me of a joke that went around a few years back: When is it bedtime at the Neverland Ranch? When the big hand touches the little hand.

Comment: Chronometric-indicator-synchronism?

Comment: @Brendon: Geez, you made me flash on the [chrono-synclastic infundibulum](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chronosynclastic%20infundibulum)...

Comment: _Superposition_ (my answer) is the technical term for when the clock hands meet, but there is no slang term. (Which is pretty cool, BTW; so it's _цагер_ in Macedonia 12 times a day? Is that an occasion for a drink?)

Comment: I do wonder what's the purpose of this word - can you explain?  Why does this exist in Macedonian do you think?

Comment: @Julia: I too am baffled. Given there are 12 (or is it 11 or 13?) such times, each occuring twice every day, what possible context could there be for this to be a *useful* word? You couldn't arrange to meet anyone "at cager", for example.

Comment: The superposition of clock hands occurs eleven times every twelve hours: at 1 ¹⁄₁₁ o’clock, 2 ²⁄₁₁, 3 ³⁄₁₁, 4 ⁴⁄₁₁, 5 ⁵⁄₁₁, 6 ⁶⁄₁₁, 7 ⁷⁄₁₁, 8 ⁸⁄₁₁, 9 ⁹⁄₁₁, 10 ¹⁰⁄₁₁, and 11 ¹¹⁄₁₁ (the last of course being 12 o’clock). If I were coining a word for this in English, I would probably use *elevenses*: The time is now ten elevenses.

Comment: Oh. But I like @belisarius's *eclipse*. The time is now ten eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the clock hands overlap, they are said to be *[superimposed](http://www.wordnik.com/words/superimpose)*.

Asking someone calculate exactly when the clock hands would be superimposed -- the times of *[superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_angle_problem#When_are_hour_and_minute_hands_of_a_clock_superimposed.3F)* -- was/is apparently used as an [interview question](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=4078172).

Comment: Just be careful not to talk to any physicists. Telling them that their clock hands are in superposition might get them excited.

Comment: *Superimposed* / *superposition* do not necessarily relate to the clock's hands (alone).

Comment: OP: "Is there a single word when the clock hands meet?" Answer: "Yes, they are _superimposed_." Read the links. You understand that answers on this site are in response to the specific questions posed, yes?

Comment: Superimposed by itself doesn't refer to the clock hands overlapping, but anything that overlaps. Therefore, it isn't exactly what "цагер" means. The correct answer would be that there is no such word in English, but since you are concerned with your answer being accepted, rather that what I feel answers my question better, here you are the rep.

Comment: Actually, see my other comment, which noted that there is no equivalent _slang_ term in English. If that's the answer you were looking for, then that's the answer you should accept.

Comment: It's cool, this whole discussion answered my question. Which answer I accept is irrelevant for me, but I will do justice to the one concerned about it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of an English word for "when the clock hands meet".  Some phrases in use, in increasing order of Google freqency, are "clock hands overlap", "clock hands coincide", and "clock hands meet", none of which register at all in [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clock+hands+overlap%2Cclock+hands+meet%2Cclock+hands+coincide&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), even though the [clockless phrases](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hands+overlap%2Chands+meet%2Chands+coincide&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) do.